# Если есть UPDATE, иначе INSERT

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица без первичного ключа:

```
"user_id" / INT / NOT NULL
"start_time" / DATETIME / NOT NULL
"stop_time" / DATETIME / NULL
```

Я знаю про конструкцию `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, но в данном случае мне нужно проверить не ключ (которого нет) на дубликат. Уникальных индексов тут быть не может, так как start_time может быть одинаковым у разных пользователей. Проверить нужно есть ли уже определённый `start_time` у конкретного `user_id`, и, если есть, дополнить запись информацией о `stop_time`, иначе вставить все три значения. Желательно без предварительных выборок - одним запросом.

**Так можно? Если да, то как это правильно написать?**

Comment: вы же знаете, наверное, что индекс как и ключ может состоять из нескольких полей, да?

Comment: Первичный ключ должен быть всегда. В вашем случае напрашивается ключ состоящий одновременно из двух полей user_id и start_time

Comment: @teran, эммм... по-ходу нет ))

Comment: @Mike, для этого же не нужно создавать дополнительное поле? Просто `user_id` и `start_time` делаются уникальными/первичными и всё, так?

Comment: Только не "уникальными/первичными", а "уникальным/первичным", в единственном числе, ключ только один, но состоящий из двух полей

Comment: @Mike, ну да, естественно! Просто никогда не сталкивался с ключами более чем из одного значения. Запрос отработал корректно, спасибо за комментарии.